# Why i get this exception( UnsatisfiedDependencyException)

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa, javabeans, factory

## Exception

```
Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the condition evaluation report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2023-09-29T20:44:57.421+04:00 ERROR 28232 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'simurqDbMain': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0: Error creating bean with name 'userServiceImpl' defined in file [C:\Users\Elshan\Documents\NetBeansProjects\Simurq\SimurqDb\target\classes\net\simurq\simurqdb\services\impl\UserServiceImpl.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 1: Error creating bean with name 'userRepository' defined in net.simurq.simurqdb.repository.UserRepository defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on JpaConfig: Not a managed type: class net.simurq.simurqdb.entity.User
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:801) ~[spring-beans-6.0.12.jar:6.0.12]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:240) ~[spring-beans-6.0.12.jar:6.0.12]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1352) ~[spring-beans-6.0.12.jar:6.0.12]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1189) ~[spring-beans-6.0.12.jar:6.0.12]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:560) ~[spring-beans-6.0.12.jar:6.0.12]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:520) ~[spring-beans-6.0.12.jar:6.0.12]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:325) ~[spring-beans-6.0.12.jar:6.0.12]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-6.0.12.jar:6.0.12]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323) ~[spring-beans-6.0.12.jar:6.0.12]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-6.0.12.jar:6.0.12]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:973) ~[spring-beans-6.0.12.jar:6.0.12]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:942) ~[spring-context-6.0.12.jar:6.0.12]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:608) ~[spring-context-6.0.12.jar:6.0.12]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:146) ~[spring-boot-3.1.4.jar:3.1.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:737) ~[spring-boot-3.1.4.jar:3.1.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:439) ~[spring-boot-3.1.4.jar:3.1.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315) ~[spring-boot-3.1.4.jar:3.1.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1309) ~[spring-boot-3.1.4.jar:3.1.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1298) ~[spring-boot-3.1.4.jar:3.1.4]
    at net.simurq.simurqdb.SimurqDbMain.main(SimurqDbMain.java:23) ~[classes/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'userServiceImpl' defined in file [C:\Users\Elshan\Documents\NetBeansProjects\Simurq\SimurqDb\target\classes\net\simurq\simurqdb\services\impl\UserServiceImpl.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 1: Error creating bean with name 'userRepository' defined in net.simurq.simurqdb.repository.UserRepository defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on JpaConfig: Not a managed type: class net.simurq.simurqdb.entity.User
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:801) ~[spring-beans-6.0.12.jar:6.0.12]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:240) ~[spring-beans-6.0.12.jar:6.0.12]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1352) ~[spring-beans-6.0.12.jar:6.0.12]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1189) ~[spring-beans-6.0.12.jar:6.0.12]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:560) ~[spring-beans-6.0.12.jar:6.0.12]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:520) ~[spring-beans-6.0.12.jar:6.0.12]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:325) ~[spring-beans-6.0.12.jar:6.0.12]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-6.0.12.jar:6.0.12]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323) ~[spring-beans-6.0.12.jar:6.0.12]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-6.0.12.jar:6.0.12]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:254) ~[spring-beans-6.0.12.jar:6.0.12]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1417) ~[spring-beans-6.0.12.jar:6.0.12]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1337) ~[spring-beans-6.0.12.jar:6.0.12]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:910) ~[spring-beans-6.0.12.jar:6.0.12]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:788) ~[spring-beans-6.0.12.jar:6.0.12]
    ... 19 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userRepository' defined in net.simurq.simurqdb.repository.UserRepository defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on JpaConfig: Not a managed type: class net.simurq.simurqdb.entity.User
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1770) ~[spring-beans-6.0.12.jar:6.0.12]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:598) ~[spring-beans-6.0.12.jar:6.0.12]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:520) ~[spring-beans-6.0.12.jar:6.0.12]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:325) ~[spring-beans-6.0.12.jar:6.0.12]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-6.0.12.jar:6.0.12]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323) ~[spring-beans-6.0.12.jar:6.0.12]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-6.0.12.jar:6.0.12]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:254) ~[spring-beans-6.0.12.jar:6.0.12]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1417) ~[spring-beans-6.0.12.jar:6.0.12]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1337) ~[spring-beans-6.0.12.jar:6.0.12]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:910) ~[spring-beans-6.0.12.jar:6.0.12]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:788) ~[spring-beans-6.0.12.jar:6.0.12]
    ... 33 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a managed type: class net.simurq.simurqdb.entity.User
    at org.hibernate.metamodel.model.domain.internal.JpaMetamodelImpl.managedType(JpaMetamodelImpl.java:192) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.9.Final.jar:6.2.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.metamodel.model.domain.internal.MappingMetamodelImpl.managedType(MappingMetamodelImpl.java:467) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.9.Final.jar:6.2.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.metamodel.model.domain.internal.MappingMetamodelImpl.managedType(MappingMetamodelImpl.java:97) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.9.Final.jar:6.2.9.Final]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaMetamodelEntityInformation.<init>(JpaMetamodelEntityInformation.java:82) ~[spring-data-jpa-3.1.4.jar:3.1.4]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaEntityInformationSupport.getEntityInformation(JpaEntityInformationSupport.java:69) ~[spring-data-jpa-3.1.4.jar:3.1.4]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactory.getEntityInformation(JpaRepositoryFactory.java:246) ~[spring-data-jpa-3.1.4.jar:3.1.4]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactory.getTargetRepository(JpaRepositoryFactory.java:211) ~[spring-data-jpa-3.1.4.jar:3.1.4]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactory.getTargetRepository(JpaRepositoryFactory.java:194) ~[spring-data-jpa-3.1.4.jar:3.1.4]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactory.getTargetRepository(JpaRepositoryFactory.java:81) ~[spring-data-jpa-3.1.4.jar:3.1.4]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getRepository(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:317) ~[spring-data-commons-3.1.4.jar:3.1.4]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.lambda$afterPropertiesSet$5(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:279) ~[spring-data-commons-3.1.4.jar:3.1.4]
    at org.springframework.data.util.Lazy.getNullable(Lazy.java:245) ~[spring-data-commons-3.1.4.jar:3.1.4]
    at org.springframework.data.util.Lazy.get(Lazy.java:114) ~[spring-data-commons-3.1.4.jar:3.1.4]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.afterPropertiesSet(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:285) ~[spring-data-commons-3.1.4.jar:3.1.4]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.java:132) ~[spring-data-jpa-3.1.4.jar:3.1.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1817) ~[spring-beans-6.0.12.jar:6.0.12]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1766) ~[spring-beans-6.0.12.jar:6.0.12]
    ... 44 common frames omitted
```

## SimurqDbMain

```
package net.simurq.simurqdb;
/**
 *
 * @author Elshan
 */

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import java.util.List;
import net.simurq.simurqdb.entity.User;
import net.simurq.simurqdb.services.inter.UserService;

@SpringBootApplication
public class SimurqDbMain {
    
     private final UserService userService;

    public SimurqDbMain(UserService userService) {
        this.userService = userService;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SimurqDbMain.class, args);
    }

    public void listUsers() {
        // Tüm kullanıcıları getir
        List<User> userList = userService.getAllUsers();

        // Kullanıcıları listeleyin
        for (User user : userList) {
            System.out.println("Kullanıcı Adı: " + user.getUserName());
            System.out.println("E-posta: " + user.getEmail());
           
        }
    }
    
   
}
```

## UserServiceImpl

```
Userpackage net.simurq.simurqdb.services.impl;


import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;
import net.simurq.simurqdb.entity.User;
import net.simurq.simurqdb.repository.UserRepository;
import net.simurq.simurqdb.services.inter.UserService;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.argon2.Argon2PasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

@Service
@Transactional
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService{

    private final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(UserServiceImpl.class);
    DataSource dataSource;
    private final UserRepository userRepository;
    private final Argon2PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

     @Autowired
    public UserServiceImpl(UserRepository userRepository, Argon2PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder) {
        
        this.userRepository = userRepository;
        this.passwordEncoder = passwordEncoder; 
        
    }

    @Override
    public User getUserById(Long userId) {
        Optional<User> userOptional = userRepository.findById(userId);
        return userOptional.orElse(null);
    }

    @Override
    public List<User> getAllUsers() {
       return userRepository.findAll();
    }
```

## application.yml

spring:
datasource:
url: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydb
username: username
password: pass
driver-class-name: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
jpa:
hibernate:
ddl-auto: update
show-sql: true
database-platform: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
entity-scan:
base-packages: net.simurq.simurqdb.entity
spring.security:
user:
password:
encoder: argon2

```
I tried start project and I always get error.What is the reason for this error?
```